# how to preview my php table without having other symbol at the end of the word

Tags: php

Currently i 'm able to show my content in php table but the content of table contain a lot of  or  symbol how could i remove those unnecessary, is there any better way? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZxWf.png)symbol

```html
<?php
// This file I have named it getdata.php
// And you will see why
include("config.php");
//Query of facebook database
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "select * from my_conference")
          or die("Failed to query database");
        

//Output results
if(!$result)
{
    mysqli_close();
    echo json_encode("There was an error running the query: " . mysqli_error());
}
elseif(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
    mysqli_close();
    echo json_encode("No results returned");
}
else
{
    $header = false;
 $output_string = "";
    $output_string .=  "<table border='1'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if(!$header)
        {
            $output_string .= "<tr>";
            foreach($row as $header => $value)
            {
                $output_string .= "<th>{$header}</th>";
            }
            $output_string .= "</tr>";
        }
        $output_string .= "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $value)
        {
            $output_string .= "<th>{$value}</th>";
        }
        $output_string .= "</tr>";
    }
    $output_string .= "</table>";
}
 echo date("Y-m");

// This echo for jquery 
echo json_encode($output_string);

?>
```

Comment: You should not use `<th>...</th>` around cell values. Use `<td>...</td>` instead. Do not use `json_encode()` around the output of `$output_string` unless you use `json_decode()` elsewhere. Also take notice of this, next time: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `json_encode()` on HTML data without decoding it with `json_decode()` and expect it to properly render.

You don't really need `json_encode()` to simply render a table.

Instead of using  `$.getJSON()`  from jQuery, you can simply use  `$.get()` or `$.post()` and then use a callback to render the contents directly into a div like this:

`$.get("getdata.php", function(result) { $("myTable").html(result); });`

And then remove all occurances of `json_encode()` from your PHP script and all should be fine..